# in node.js validate an object's interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I need to validate the interface of an object in node.js, so basically check that the object has the methods I need before I invoke those methods on it.

I remember it was possible to perform this check using chriso's 
[validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js), but I can't find any reference on its documentation.

Is it my memory that fails? And in this case, how can I do it?

---

EDIT
In order to better explain what I want this is an example

```
var myObj = function(parObj){
  parObj.hasInterface('methodA', 'methodB', 'methodC')
    .throwErr(new Error("object must have the right interface"));

  this.myFun = function(){
    return parObj.methodA(/*...*/);
  };
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `typeof obj.function === "function"`?

Comment: @t.niese I added an example. What you propose means that I should do it for each method I expect making the code a little bit too verbose

Comment: And what is the problem with your proposed code? You can place the `typedef` check in the `hasInterface` method. But I would suggest to do `hasInterface(obj, ['methodA', 'methodB', 'methodC'])`. Extending the prototype of `Object`  is a bead idea.